# Rust reading input from console after printing

Tags: rust

I am just making a little program and I'm trying to get input from the user through the console and this is the code I have:

```
print!("Enter values seperated by spaces: ");
let mut input = String::new();
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
    Ok(_n) => println!("{}", input),
    Err(e) => println!("error: {}", e),
}
```

But instead of printing `Enter values seperated by spaces:`  and then reads the input and prints the input, it reads the input first, and then prints `Enter values seperated by spaces:`  and then it prints the input. How can I make it so that it prints `Enter values seperated by spaces:`  first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush your output stream

```
use std::io::{Write, stdout}

...

print!("Enter values separated by spaces: ");
stdout().flush();
```

By default, most modern terminals are line-buffered for efficiency. If you want to override this behavior, you have to flush the stream yourself.

Comment: "By default, most modern terminals are line-buffered for efficiency." FWIW this is a language / libc property rather than a terminal one, the buffering happens inside the application and regulates how often the `write` syscall is actually called. The line buffering of Rust's stdout happens in the standard library (and stderr tends to be unbuffered, which is why you can get strange result if you mix stderr and stdout output without being careful).